# .htaccess deny access to specific files? more than one

Tags: php, security, apache, .htaccess, file

I am able to disable access to a file with `.htaccess`, but I don't know how to disallow multiple files to be viewed (directly, not from includes)

They are `.php` files so I can't disable a file type.

```
<FILES ... ? 

</FILES>
```

For example `"home.php, file.php, test.php"` how do I disallow access to all three files with that tag or similar?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to exclude files based on regular expressions, you could use FilesMatch instead of Files, e.g.:

```
<FilesMatch ^((home|test|file)\.php$|mysecretfolder|asecretpicture\.jpe?g)$>
...
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Perfect, I love the piping for each file name, just what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: Caveat: Use start and end of the string, if you want to exclude /test.php, but not /public/test.php or /test.php.bak

Comment: That is the most useful thing I've seen all week. Granted, it's just past 2pm on a Monday, but still.

Comment: Caveat: Including `mysecretfolder` in the `FilesMatch` directive **will not** deny access to all files within that directory.

Answer (score 11):

Looks like you have to exclude those files one by one:

```
<files home.php>
Deny/Allow/Whatever
</files>
<files file.php>
...
```

You can use `*.gif` in `<files>` or `something*`, but as home.php, file.php and test.php can't really be grouped with a "*", this is probably the only way to go.

Answer (score 6):

since apache 2.4

```
<FilesMatch "\.htaccess|config\.php">

    Require all denied

</FilesMatch>
```

instead of

```
<FilesMatch "\.htaccess|config\.php">

    Order allow,deny 
    Deny from all 

</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: In my case it did not work when escaping the dot (`\.`). There was no error, but the file was still accessible. Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)

Answer (score 2):

## Solution for 2023

#### One-liner for detecting multiple files and multiple file extensions at the same time you could use the following patterns:

```
(?:readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?)
```

**Note:**

The first set of parentheses up to `"\."`, is the file names/patterns and second set of parentheses after `"\."`, would determine your file extensions. Feel free to `add/remove` file(s) and file extension(s) to/from the example I provided you with, to suit your needs!

---

**For example:**

##### Matching multiple files with different file extensions and returning `"Forbidden"` to the user:

```
<FilesMatch "(?:readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?)">
      Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

##### Matching multiple files with different file extensions and returning `"404"` to the user:

```
<FilesMatch "(?:readme|license|changelog|-config|-sample)\.(?:php|md|txt|html?)">
      Redirect 404
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: I am curious as to why we need opening and closing '?' for the extension portion but only an opening '?' in the filename portion.

Comment: @MichaelMoriarty The opening `?:` has a different meaning than the `?` one! `?:` is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471/15040627). The last `?` is one of the [regular expression quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Quantifiers) which makes the character `l` optional! In some stacks, in addition to `.html` files there are `.htm` files as well. So to detect both `.html` and `.htm` files, at the same time, we would use `?` to cover both scenarios!

Comment: Thanks @Ruvee I would gather then that I could do (?:s?html?|s?pgp|jpe?g) and get shtml, html, htm, sphp, php, jpeg, and jpg

Comment: @MichaelMoriarty Yes correct!