# How to restrict access to a PHP file?

Tags: php, http

I'd like to restrict access to a PHP file on my server.  This PHP file takes data from an HTTP GET request and appends it to a file.  Simple.  But I don't want this PHP file executed unless the HTTP request is generated from within the smartphone app I've developed.

I don't want to authenticate each user individually.  I want my app, and only my app, to be able to send the request to the PHP file.  I don't want people typing in a similarly formed request (http://www.mydomain.com/check.php?string=blahblahblah) into a browser and have the same impact.

I have thought about checking the HTTP_USER_AGENT, or some other variable, but I fear that they might be easy to spoof too.  I could embed a key into my app that I look for, but that key could also be compromised.

The next step would be to have the server send me a challenge to which I respond appropriately.  Or I could even look into PKI.  But what's a relatively easy way to do this, given that I am not trying to protect anything of real value, just to prevent minor vandalism.

Am I trying to reinvent the wheel here?  Is there already an easy, proven way to do this?

Comment: It is in the nature of what you are doing that there is no 100% fool-proof way to do this. The most secure thing I can think of is to generate a unique key for each instance of your mobile app, store a list of key -> IMEI relationships in a database to validate requests against (which obviously contain this information, preferably encrypted in some way) and perform all requests from your app over HTTPS. But even then if someone manages to obtain the key and IMEI pair of a handset, it will be spoofable.

Comment: This topic should answer you question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182936/htaccess-deny-access-to-specific-files-more-than-one

Comment: If you want to discourage automated bots from flooding your server with garbage you can set the PHP script to sleep for 30 seconds after each request. If the phone app does not need a response (you can use cURL to send a non-blocking request) it makes bot attacks long and tedious and easy to spot and block by ip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FWIW, here is the most secure method I can think of without seriously affecting performance - essentially the RESTful(ish) way, as to ramp it up any further would require multiple requests and connection state information stored on the server:

- The app and the server have an identical salt string hard-coded, unique to each successive version of the mobile app. This string *must* be kept private.
- When a user installs the app on their device, the app contacts your server and informs it of the version of the app, and the device's [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity), which the APIs for whatever mobile platform you are working with should enable you to retrieve.
- The server generates a unique key for that instance of the app which is sent back to the app and stored on the device, and stores it in the server-side database with the IMEI and the installed version.
- During day-to-day operation (i.e. when making the request outlined in the question) the app follows this procedure:

  - Retrieve the following information:

    1. Device IMEI
    2. App key
    3. App version
    4. Hard-coded salt string
    5. Randomly generated string for additional salt (derivative of the current timestamp with microseconds is always good for a reasonable amount of entropy).
  - Concatenate all these pieces of information together, preferably with hard-coded padding between them and produce a hash of the resulting string.
  - Send to the server the following pieces of information along with the actual request data (maybe in cookies for a *tiny* extra bit of security):

    1. Generated hash
    2. App key
    3. Randomly generated string used as additional salt
- The server now uses the App key to retrieve the device IMEI and app version of that instance from the database, and uses that information along with the hard-coded salt string for the version ID and the additional salt string sent by the device to construct the hash. If the hash generated on the server matches the hash generated by the mobile device, the request is good, if not reject it.
- *All* communication in this process is over HTTPS.

In order to break through this system and successfully spoof a request, an attacker would need to know the following:

1. Device IMEI
2. App key
3. App version
4. Hard-coded salt
5. The mechanism that you use to generate the hash (the precise format of the input string and the hashing algorithm).

Obviously if you are working with the mobile device 1 - 3 are easy to extract, but 4 and 5 cannot be found without reverse engineering the app (which there is literally nothing you can do to prevent, for people with the knowledge and the patience to do it).

A man-in-the-middle attack would be basically impossible - even after breaking through the SSL (which is non-trivial, to say the least) and reverse engineering the app to get 4 and 5, 1-3 cannot be retrieved without a brute force attack on the hash, which is sufficiently complex that this would take an average of several hundred million years (see [this page](http://unwrongest.com/projects/password-strength/) to see how I arrived at that figure), especially if one of the three is of a variable length - which the app version string could easily be.

Answer (score 3):

Define a salt in both your app and php file, then hash that salt combined with the current time. That's unlikely to ever get spoofed.

```
$hash = sha1(time() . 'bladieblasalt');

if($_GET['hash'] == sha1(time() . 'samehash'))
{
    echo 'valid';
}
```

Comment: The spoffing problem comes from people who may disassemble the phone app.

Comment: Plus this would require the time on the mobile device and the server to be identical, and assumes that the request will take <1 second which over a mobile network it may not.

Comment: You could refine it to a scope of say 5 seconds, but if you're worried your phone app would get disassbembled I wouldn't have a clue what you can do instead.

Comment: Well reverse engineering is impossible to work around. You can break into anything if you know how it works underneath. But I still don't like the timestamp idea on its own, looking at my phone now the clock is 2 minutes different from that of my computer, despite the fact that I have both of them set to update from pool.ntp.org (same NTP on both devices). If I manually force an update they're back in sync, but I think it proves this can't be relied on enough to really be a solid option.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you would need to implement ssl into your app else someone with little knowledge could simply have there phone connected on there wifi and sniff the traffic between the app and your site with wireshark or cain and abel ect. and get the url and any parameters passed, no need to disassemble anything.

App connects to your site and user logs in, whether its a guest or a member your server assigns the app a request id and this key/token is passed along with every request & validated within a session on your server.

The token would look like:
`UNIQUE_REQUEST_ID_ASSIGNED_BY_SERVER:APPsIP:APPsTIME` Encrypt this string and send it as a `$_GET['token']`

Then on your server decrypt the string and `explode()` the string into its parts and check against a database or session that the request id,ip and the time match ect, if all is good do which ever.

Much like a secure login system assign a unique salt for each user and store that along side the users request id.

The bottom line is, just make it hard for an abuser to abuse the system. 99% of people wont even think to fiddle and the other 1% get there ips blocked.

Comment: IP blocking is dangerous with mobile devices, due to the fact that most mobile networks NAT to the point where a few hundred thousand devices may share a handful of public IPs. You are in danger of blocking many of you users because of one guy trying to break in to the system.

Comment: Yeah your right, tho i was thinking that any forged request would not be from within the phone tho its still viable that the abuser could use there phone connection attached to a laptop :s

Comment: Indeed, or simply a HSD/UPA modem. Plus with the way things are moving with mobile enabled tablets, I can see a point in the not so distant future where people use them instead of laptops. Depressingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want anything per-user, but only per-app, you will have to rely on a secret built into the application. Anyone disassembling the application will eventually be able to find that, so some obfuscation might help, but it won't keep determined people off your page.

That said, there is little point in using any public key crypto. As the app-side is what spoofers might be interested in, they'd already have access to the more valuable half of a key pair. So you might as well use some approach using a shared secret.

What you really want to check is the authenticity of the transferred data. So simply take the core of that data (i.e. all fields which really matter), concatenate them with the shared secret, hash the result and transfer it as a message digest. The server performs the same calculation and checks that the computed digest matches the transferred one. If it does, the sender of that message must have known the shared secret.

There still is some chance for a replay attack, i.e. someone recording a valid message and repeating it later on. You can detect exact duplicates on the server side, and prevent delayed replay by including a timestamp in the signed part of the message. If your server allows for a huge difference between client and server timestamps, it will have to keep duplicate information for that same amount of time. If it only accepts small differences, it can work with a smaller duplicate cache, but users with malconfigured devices might be annoyed as the server is more likely to reject their requests as being too old.

One more note: you wrote about a `GET` request causing a write to some file. I would always associate some state-changing operation with a `POST` instead. If the app is your own, it doesn't matter that much, but browsers are known to retransmit `GET` requests without asking the user, thereby causing duplicate requests for some action.

Answer (score 1):

There's no guarantee method.  You can use oauth authentication... Depending upon what platform your using and how your deploying app to the phone, maybe perhaps you can compile your key into the application itself?  Anything can & will always be cracked, there is no 100% security... But no shame in trying. :)

Personally what I use for my mobile apps is RESTful authentication with regular login/pass pair the token based communication till it expires. :)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests can be built character by character in whatever way the sender wants. Spoofing will always be possible.

Comment: If you think I'm wrong, at least explain why. We're all here to learn.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I suspect whoever has did it not because this is wrong (it isn't) but because the answer is not long enough. You don't supply any real explanation as to *why* this is, and maybe you could suggest ways to minimise the risk. Either that or they are just grumpy/an idiot.

Comment: @DaveRandom - Thanks Dave. It won't encourage me to use 2 words where one will do, but I take your point.

Comment: Yes I agree there is definitely no need for long text with little information just to pad it out, it's all about the quality of the information you provide at the end of the day. But in this instance I think the quantity could be reasonably increased to assist the OP in understanding exactly why what he wants to do is more or less impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Just add authorisation (logins, passwords, sessions etc and/or "API keys") to your PHP application and then let your phone app to authorise first before sending the needed requests. You probably didn't consider that because if your script is simple that might add some clutter to it, but then again almost every web system needs that, and you will face that as well eventually.

Let you phone application to log into your PHP app via HTTPS to exclude interception.