# Only allow script from server to access files

Tags: php, security, .htaccess

Only allow script to run or get request from the PHP files on the web server.

- For eg. you have a file on your web-sever `http://example.com/libs/comment.php`
- Only allow other PHP,or JS file get request from this file (means run this file and perform desired result)
- If any user try a direct access to this file he/she will get error or 404 any other message

Here this `comment.php` is just an example. The libs folder contains lots of files, and the above applies to all of them. My preference is to use a .htacces method or a mode-rewrite of the folder like 666,777 etc.
I know this is not a real questions aksing just to improve security make almost sercure sites.

Comment: I guess people at serverfault.com can help you out better than we can...

Comment: @rsplak oops. some other can try. thanks for info

Answer (score 4):

Well, the simplest way to do this, is define a constant in your front controller (*presumably, index.php*):

```
define('SECURE', true);
```

Then, test for it at the beginning of any included file:

```
!defined('SECURE') and exit;
```

This will prevent *any* client side access (*including calling assets from the page, via JavaScript, or `src` attributes; everything really*)

Other provisions best be made for security, as recommended in other answers.

Comment: this can be little complex. if you have sessions to work with

Comment: @BasicBridge How do sessions add complexity?

Comment: While this would work, having to edit each and every file doesn't really sound like “the simplest way” to me.

Comment: @MvG Really? Recursive directory search and replace: `(?-m)^<\?php` with `<?php !defined('SECURE') and exit;`. Alternatively, you can match `\A` (*instead of `(?-m)^`*). These expressions will match the first `<?php` only. This all depends on your coding style and, as always, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 3):

You already mention `.htaccess` in your question. Simply create such a file in your `libs` directory and enter the following directives:

```
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
```

See the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html) for details about the [Order](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#order) and [Deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny) directives.

Note that the error would be `403 Forbidden` instead of `404 Not Found`.

Note that this will deny *all* access via HTTP to the files in your `libs` dir. Your other PHP files can `include` or `require` those files, as this is a purely server-side operation. If you for some reason need one PHP script to execute another via HTTP, then you could change the oder to `deny, allow` and also add a line `Allow from 127.0.0.1` in order to allow local requests to proceed. But I doubt you'd have your PHP scripts talking to one another via HTTP.

If you need JavaScript documents on the client side to not access these files, then this cannot reasonably be done: anything the client broser can do, the client can do without executing your code, at least without executing all of it the way you inteded it to. There is a question on [how to restrict access to a PHP file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11467098/1468366) which discuss some steps to prevent easy vandalism, but none of these will keep determined hackers from using your scripts.

Answer (score 2):

If the browser can access it via `<script>` or `<style>`, so can the user.

If you only want the server to access it, pull it out of the `public` directory, to make it web-inaccessible.

Comment: i agree with you but it's not possible to all the files out of the server directory.

Comment: Although what you say is true, I don't see what php files have to do with `<script>` or `<style>` tags.

Comment: @MvG: He wants JavaScript files to be able to access it, but users don't. Which is impossible.

Comment: @Truth, thanks for the comment; it seems I completely missed the part about “or JS”.

Answer (score 0):

you can define a constant before including the said file. Something like:

```
<?php
    define('MY_CONSTANT', 1);
    include_once('libs/comment.php');
    ...
```

Then inside the comment.php you can put something like this:

```
<?php
    if(!defined('MY_CONSTANT')) {
       header("Status: 404 Not Found");
    }
    ...
```

More or less you would have the same effect as the one you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, get a response from a php call, like `http://example.com/libs/myphp.php?arg=value` and from what I read it was almost impossible to hide. So I decided to implement a different approach. Create a function in the php file, include the file in the script, call the function and assign the result to a variable in javascript. That way everything is hidden to client.

You will have in `myphp.php`

```
`<?php  
myFunction($param){
  // do your task
  return $result;
}
?>`
```

Then in your page, `index.php`

```
<?php
require_once( "myphp.php");
$param = //whatever params
$my_var = myFunction($param);    
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = <?php echo $my_var; ?>;  
// or
var myArray = <?php echo json_encode($my_var); ?>;
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myVar; 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for lock file where it can be executed by the server only.
the simplest way is changing the entire folder or file permission.

For example, you want to use some image from folder images
you can set images folder permission to 700
Which means only server user can read write or execute the file.
Rest of visitors and public user will get 404 error when they try to access it.