# script that runs before being able to upload file to FTP

Tags: php, android, file-upload, ftp

I'm trying to create a security mechanism that only allows my application to upload files to my FTP (username and password login is not enough). To achieve this I was thinking of creating a key that is built in to the app, and before any file can be uploaded to the FTP this key has to be read and verified. If it's correct, then the file can be uploaded.

Is this something that is possible to do, and would this approach be preferred? Does anyone have any pointers on how to do this?

*(note: i'm not asking for any code, just some pointers on where to start, since my searches aren't getting my anywhere)*

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just restrict the FTP server to your IP address?

Comment: Using a special Handshake system would be good. Hard-coding keys into your app is not a good idea. I myself am trying to find a way to secure my proprietary server from being accessed by code copied from my open source client.

Comment: @siidheesh I know this is not your question but I will say this: If your client code is open source, there is literally nothing (at least, nothing generic/decentralised/in the spirit of open source) you can do to prevent someone looking at the algorithms in your client code and mimicking them to gain access to your server. The only thing you could do would be to make that element of the application closed source.

Comment: Haha yes I agree with you, but you can't hide parts of text files, and my client is a Java class intended to be compiled with an external JAR

Comment: @DaveRandom It will be possible to run the application (android) on multiple handset and from any part of the world. So I don't think that will work in my case

Comment: @ChristerWilliamPersson OK, that won't work then. Do you mean FTP or HTTP? You can't run PHP on android, and running a PHP driven FTP server sounds like a bad plan. Implementing the app key/handshake system is a *lot* easier over HTTP than it would be over FTP

Comment: @DaveRandom Alright, i'm not bound to using FTP in anyway, I just thought it would be easiest since my knowledge of server communication is quite limited. So you're talking about having a PHP webpage and uploading files (via POST?) to this page and then storing it on the server?

Comment: Yes, I'm thinking an HTTP POST with a file upload, and a couple of extra form fields can be used to implement some kind of app key setup. Before we go down that road though, you need to think about exactly what this extra auth token system will do, how it will work, how it can be validated on the server side etc. Do you want a hard-coded app key for every instance of your application? Hang on a second this is triggering a memory of another question I answered quite recently, let me dig it out...

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467098/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-php-file/11468080#11468080

Comment: wow, that was actually pretty spot on. Thanks alot! :) I will look in to it. Copy it to the answer section if you feel like it, and I'll accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no point in reproducing an answer from another question verbatim, so I'll just post [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467098/how-to-restrict-access-to-a-php-file/11468080#11468080) to it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are worried about unsecured wi-fi, etc, you can either use SFTP or tunneling over SSH e.g. with connectbot
the use of public key crypto will will make sniffing harder.

if this is too much work for the intended userbase, you could generate one time passes (like google authenticator) and upload your file with a POST form or something.

if you are afraid of the key itself getting stolen (compromised device), there is little you can do..