# how do you get users to not access files in the database

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, webmatrix

I am currently building a website in `Webmatrix` and right now users can access images and files on the server, like this:

```
localhost:8080/uploads/images/64/facebook_64.png
```

How can I do it so they cant access these files.

I it helps I am writing in `Javascript` , `CSS` and `HTML` and I won't work with `PHP` if it is not really necessary.

Comment: Do you want these images to be seen using the `<img src="" />` tag?

Comment: are you using a user/permissions management plugin?

Comment: A.I.G yes and mike dont now what you mean (i'm new to server managment)

Comment: You can restrict certain files by using `.htaccess` if you want to go that route. I.e.: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/2182936/ @Liam_Rab3

Comment: I know this is beyond the scope of the question, but sometimes starting with a pre-built content management system is better for you because it already addresses user permissions and folder restrictions. These are more secure than ad-hoc projects. So, a user with administrator permissions has unrestricted access, registered users have greater access, unregistered users must register for access.

Answer (score 1):

Add a .htaccess file in the top folder that you want no one accessing with the following

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Note: This means that you also won't be able to show them to users using img tags or any other method that requires the user to send a request to the image. However, the server can still use them.

Comment: <strike>won't that keep the system from using the resources?</strike>

Comment: What Mike said is true. The OP can however limit to certain files, while using `.htacess` and not restrict the entire folder.

Comment: See this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/2182936/ that's what I meant by that. More specifically http://stackoverflow.com/a/2182961/ - Also http://stackoverflow.com/q/11728976/ - It's an option.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Not if your site is only going to use client-side technologies like html, css and javascript.

Any asset that you will need for your site, will be fetched using a http request and if your site / application can do that without any server-side technologies / authentication, so can any user.

You need a server-side technology like for example php if you want to use assets in your site while not making them publicly accessible.

Comment: it is just that everytime i try to setup a server in php or sql it just dont work, i dont really know how